# Is it possible to define double aws configuration for paperclip in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

First let me tell u what I need and I'd like to know is it possible or not. Let's say I have two aws configuration. And I'm using paperclip for files in rails. But I'm keeping old files on another aws. So I'd like to do something like check the file is exist in first aws and if its not exist there check other one. Can I do that?

I hope I could have explained correctly what I need. I'm just wondering is it possible or not. And I'm also open for advices if its possible.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say `I have two aws configuration` - do you mean 2 different accounts or something else?

Comment: yes two different accounts, actually one of them is minio server on my own server and the other one s aws but they have same configuration thats why i said two aws to make it clear.